# How do I share a UIImage between two ViewControllers programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using this custom collectionView transition:

When a cell is selected, the `UIImage` in the cell is animated to transition seamlessly into the `UIImageView` in the `detailViewController` ,as seen in the GIF in this [link](https://github.com/xxxAIRINxxx/ARNTransitionAnimator/blob/master/ARNZoomImageTransition.gif).

However the issue is, the `UIImage` in the `detailViewController`'s `UIImageView` is hard coded in, and will be the same for every selected cell from the `UICollectionView`. I have different images within my `collectionViewCell`'s and this would obviously be a problem, so I need to somehow programmatically make my `detailViewController`'s `UIImageView` Image to equal that of the selected collectionViewCell's `UIImageView` Image when the transition is completed.

Here's the code I used to try to achieve this:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, ARNImageTransitionZoomable {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

     var selectedCell = MasterCollectionViewController()

    deinit {
        println("deinit DetailViewController")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    }

    // MARK: - ARNImageTransitionZoomable

    func createTransitionImageView() -> UIImageView {
        var imageView = UIImageView(image: self.imageView.image)
        imageView.contentMode = self.imageView.contentMode
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        imageView.frame = self.imageView!.frame
        return imageView
    }

    func presentationBeforeAction() {
        self.imageView.hidden = true
    }

    func presentationCompletionAction(completeTransition: Bool) {
        self.imageView.hidden = false
        self.imageView.image = selectedCell.selectedImageView?.image
    }

    func dismissalBeforeAction() {
        self.imageView.hidden = true
    }

    func dismissalCompletionAction(completeTransition: Bool) {
        if !completeTransition {
            self.imageView.hidden = false
        }
    }


}
```

I added a variable `"selectedCell"` that is of type `MasterCollectionViewController()`, giving me reference to everything in that class.

Then in the animation/transitions completion, I attempted to set the selected cell's UIImage to that of my detailViewController's UIImageView Image with the line

```
func presentationCompletionAction(completeTransition: Bool) {
            self.imageView.hidden = false
            self.imageView.image = selectedCell.selectedImageView?.image
}
```

This didn't work, when the transition is complete, the UIImageView is just white with no image, just as it is on my storyboard. Somebody know any method I can implement?

Comment: @dahn check this out

Comment: Do you try to call `setNeedDisplay` after assign image?

Comment: after i assign the image in which line of code? @anhtu

Comment: `self.imageView.image = selectedCell.selectedImageView?.image` this line

Comment: how do i call `setNeedDisplay` correctly

Comment: did you ever figure this out?